# Unable to boot Ubuntu machine after power outage

Tags: ubuntu, boot, server-crashes

So I'm generally a web developer but a place I do some help for is asking me why this is happening after a power failure at their location...

I'm looking to get some feedback on how to do this so that I can make an educated attempt at least. I'm including some of the bootup information from the machine. The owner things it is a 2SSD machine....I'm thinking is is some kind of hardware failure but I'm not sure what actually is going on..as i'm not primarily a sys admin....

---

The system boots us in emergency mode and get stuck in this “system check” look. I also tried to run fsck but the process aborts itself. I attach further screenshots about the journal.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome. Home and End-user computing questions are off topic. beside this, Questions seeking installation, configuration or diagnostic help must include the desired end state, the specific problem or error, sufficient information about the configuration and environment to reproduce it, and attempted solutions. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers and are unlikely to get good answers. Meaning, we need a hell more information ;) I. e. dmesg, smart value, raid information, etc as more as better, please paste plain text directly instead using pictures

Comment: @djdomi tell me how to copy and paste from a terminal screen....in diagnostic bootup...

Comment: @djdomi and like 90% of the questions in here are about people's personal computer running some operating system....